# Update status bar within a custom function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, statusbar

I have a custom function (UDF) that sometimes takes a while to run. The worksheet is set to only manually refresh. I would like to display progress in the status bar when the function runs.

Within subs Application.StatusBar [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24221214/4565586).

Within functions Application.StatusBar doesn't seem to work. I've run through the code line-by-line. The status bar won't update, and no errors are thrown.

Is there something that prevents the status bar from working with functions?

I'm running Excel 2016 on Win10.

The display code, with context from the surrounding programming:

```
Function getCost(parameters)

dim variables
dim bOldStatusBar as Boolean

<web query begins>
bOldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Calculating prices between " & Origin & " and " & Destination & "."
DoEvents

<clicking buttons in IE>
Application.StatusBar = "Starting Data Import..."

<clicking buttons in IE>
Application.StatusBar = "Macro 20% Complete"

etc...

<clicking buttons in IE>
Application.StatusBar = "Macro 100% Complete"
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = bOldStatusBar

End Function
```

Comment: A function is usually used for calculations, not to change the status bar

Comment: @Davesexcel it does calculations as well; I just want to show a few simple messages in the status bar to show progress while the calculation is running.

Comment: What's the code look like?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's very similar to the code in the answer I linked, but I went back and added the relevant code with context in the question.

Comment: I think @Davesexcel might be right and we can't use the [statusbar in a UDF](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/application-statusbar-or-equivalent-for-user-defined-functions.3476931/)...I'll keep searching though.  What if you created a Sub that has your StatusBar statuses, and call the sub from the function?

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for finding that; that's what I was afraid of, but I couldn't find anything about it. I wish there was official documentation explaining this, but this is helpful.

I did try that; I created a trial sub that just tests the status bar - it worked - and then tried calling it within a function when I entered "1" as a parameter. No dice though. Your linked forum post does mention as well that that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What if you try the reverse - Call your function from a Sub that updates the status bar, instead of calling a sub from a function?

Comment: @BruceWayne that would probably work, but that's fairly clunky... That's probably what I'll end up doing though. Either that, or create a progress bar in a popup or perhaps even another cell.

Comment: Doing a message box isn't a bad idea. You can upadte the user on the progress and have them click "ok" which will also show that the user is paying attention (perhaps that's an added benefit?)  Or, instead of popping the message up at a predetermined line, what if you did a timer that sees if it's been X minutes since the macro started, and if so, then pop up? That way if a user's computer is able to whiz through this, they don't have to get an update every half second?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add *DoEvents* after updating the statusbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, as others have stated, you [cannot update the StatusBar via a function call.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Since I just faced this problem today, I though I would add a comment here. DoEvents solved my problem if included BEFORE the Application.StatusBar command. In other words, here is how my code is now:

```
DoEvents
Application.StatusBar = ">>>>>>> FORMATING: " & Format((current_line - line_start) / (line_end - line_start), "0%") & " completed <<<<<<<"
```